Movie where a college teacher goes to a mansion to seek ghosts
I remember watching this movie a while ago. It's based on a man who is invited to a mansion (?) to seek ghosts (?). I remember that in the mansion there was 1 sister and 2 brothers (1 of them was a painter) and one old lady. I think the 3 brothers thought the old lady saw ghosts and paranormal activity, and they wanted to know if the man could help her. I also think that the man falls in love with the woman in the house or something.
I don't know the year. English. Color. I remember a scene in the end of the movie where a fire started in the mansion that they were in and the main character had to follow a ghost of a kid to survive the fire. I also remember that there was a doctor in the movie or something. 

Year? Country\language? Color\B&W? And do you remember any specific scenes?

Are there 2 brothers or 3 brothers?

I don't know the year. English. Color. I remember a scene in the end of the movie where a fire started in the mansion that they were in and the main character had to follow a ghost of a kid to survive the fire. I also remember that there was a doctor in the movie or something.

They were 3 siblings, 1 girl, 2 boys.

Thanks for the extra details. Added & posted a possible match.

Sounds like the ghost film Haunted from 1995 with Aidan Quinn and Kate Beckinsale.

Professor David Ash [Quinn] is invited to Edbrook to calm the fears of the elderly nanny of the Mariell family. Nanny Tess is seeing things, and Ash's book debunking such phenomenon makes him a good choice to set her mind at ease and convince her she is just tired and stressed. But soon after arriving David too begins to doubt his senses, and watching the odd behavior of the three grown Mariell children doesn't make his task any easier. In fact, he begins to think Nanny Tess isn't really just tired and stressed out after all.

They're 3 siblings (2 brothers and a sister) and he falls in love with the sister (Beckinsale). In the end, his late sister's ghost saves him from a fire, leading him to safety. Here's the trailer:




YES! Thanks alot everybody :)
